# Combining multiple list comprehensions into a list of lists

Tags: python, numpy, list-comprehension, sudoku

I know there have been similar question to my title, but I cannot find a similar problem to the problem I have outlined below:

I am trying to get the following 9 list comprehensions to be stored into one list, so that each of the list comprehensions is itself a list within a new list:

```
a = [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)]
b = [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3,6)]
c = [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(6,9)]

d = [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(3)]
e = [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(3,6)]
f = [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(6,9)]

g = [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3)]
h = [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3,6)]
i = [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3,9)]
```

Specifically, these print out the indexes for the BLOCKS within a sudoku board. I would like have each block as a list within one list.

Would anyone be able to point me in the right direction.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if your last line is correct, fairly sure it should be

```
[(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(6,9)]
```

not

```
[(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3,9)]
```

as this is for a 3x6 grid.

Nonetheless this is a cleaner list comp for creating 9 3x3 grids:

```
[[(x0*3 + i, y0*3 + j) for x in range(3) for y in range(3)] for x0 in range(3) for y0 in range(3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I can think of two ways, both trivial rewrites of what you've got:

1) `master_list = [a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i]` That is, just take the individually named lists you've got and put them in a list.

2)

```
master_list = [
    [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(3,6)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(6,9)],

    [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(3)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(3,6)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(3,6) for j in range(6,9)],

    [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3,6)],
    [(i,j) for i in range(6,9) for j in range(3,9)],
]
```

This is essentially the same, but without the intermediate variable names.

Answer (score 0):

Rationalising a bit, you can define a function

```
def f(b, r):
    return [(i, j) for i in range(b, b+3) for j in range(*r)]
```

and drive it it with the wanted ranges

```
ml = [f(b, r) for b in range(0, 9, 3) for r in ((0, 3), (3, 6), (6, 9))]
```